# Remove views and add another view in fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` which has a list which we get from server. I want to show another screen if there is no internet with Try Again button. Till now I have created the layout and getting the list when internet is there. But when there is no internet I try to add my no internet screen in the `fragment`, but somehow this throwing me an error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4309)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4086)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4059)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1425)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my fragment layout:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/challenge_landing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/challengeLandingRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</GridLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.challenge_landing_fragment, container, false);
        setUI(view);
        initializeChallengeList();
        mChallengeManager= ChallengeManager.singleton();
        fetchChallengesFromNetwork();
        // setupPresenter(view);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }

    private void setUI(View view) {
      progressDialog = CustomProgressDialog.createDialog(getContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.loading));    
       view.findViewById(R.id.challengeLandingRV);
        mChallengeLandingContainer = (GridLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.challenge_landing);

    }

    private void initializeChallengeList() {
        mMy_challenges_Model = new ArrayList<Challenge>();
        mOpen_challenges_Model = new ArrayList<Challenge>();
        mClose_challenges_Model = new ArrayList<Challenge>();
        mAll_Challenges_model = new ArrayList<Challenge>();
        mOrderedChallegeList=new ArrayList<Challenge>();
    }

    private void fetchChallengesFromNetwork() {    
        JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
        try {
            param.put("timeline", "all");
            param.put("include_rank",true);
            param.put("registered_flag", "all");

            Log.d("FetchChallengereq ", "Req "+param.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (NetworkUtils.isConnectedToNetwork(getContext())) {             
            progressDialog.show();
            mChallengeManager.fetchChallengeList(param, new ChallengeManager.ChallengeListResponseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onRequestCompleted(int statusCode, List<Challenge> challengeList, String statusMessage,int total_challenges) {
                    Log.d("FetchChallenge ", "Response "+statusCode);
                  //  if (mProgressBar != null) mProgressBar.dismiss();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        if (statusMessage.equals("Challenges successfully fetched")) {

                            mAll_Challenges_model = challengeList;
                            separateChallenges(mAll_Challenges_model);
                            Log.d("All Challenges list", "Response "+mAll_Challenges_model.toString());

                            populateData(mChallenge_RecycleView, mOrderedChallegeList);//for my challenges
                        }    
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),statusMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }                 
                @Override
                public void onCurrentChallengesRequestCompleted(int statusCode, List<Challenge> publicchallengeList, List<Challenge> corporatechallengeList, String statusMessage, int total_challenges) {
                }
            });

        } else {
showNoInternetScreen();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.network_connection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void showNoInternetScreen() {
        final GridLayout mChallengeLandingContainer = (GridLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.challenge_landing);
        if (null != mChallengeLandingContainer) {
            //mChallengeLandingContainer.removeAllViews();
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
            view = View.inflate(view.getContext(), R.layout.content_list_fragment_no_internet, null);
            mChallengeLandingContainer.addView(view);
            TextView mRetryButton = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.retryButton);
            mRetryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (com.android.mobiefit.sdk.network.NetworkUtils.isConnectedToNetwork(getActivity())) {
                       // mChallengeLandingContainer.removeAllViews();
                        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                        if (parent != null) {
                            parent.removeView(view);
                        }
                        view = View.inflate(view.getContext(), R.layout.challenge_landing_fragment, null);
                        mChallengeLandingContainer.addView(view);
                        setUI(view);
                        initializeChallengeList();
                        mChallengeManager= ChallengeManager.singleton();
                        fetchChallengesFromNetwork();
                        // setupPresenter(view);
                        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

So I am bit confused. How to use removeView() and why am I getting this error?

Comment: Instead of this create another fragment. And check on activity for internet connection, if connection available show your list else do nothing.

Comment: Why that much code for only show NoInternetScreen . Just use a View inside your layout with `RelativeLayout` as root parent and make it VISIBLE/GONE on internet connection toggle .

Answer (score 0):

> how to use removeView()

In your onCreateView

```
 if (view != null) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.removeView(view);
    }
}
try {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.challenge_landing_fragment, container, false);
} catch (InflateException e) {

}
```

> why am I getting this error

you are instantiating dynamic layout and adding childs to it